# 'Empty tree' function causing program to crash

Tags: c, function, boolean

I have a empty_tree() function that basically returns a true value if the tree is empty and returns false if it is not.

```
bool empty_tree(AVL self)
{
    if (self == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It exists so that my program is easier to understand without comments. Now, it works fine everywhere else in my program. However when I try and use it in my insert function in place of the working:

```
if(self == NULL)
```

my program will crash. This isn't really a big deal and using the 'if (self==NULL) will suffice, but I was just wondering if anyone had any ideas as to why this would cause the program to crash. As I said, it's not extremely important so I won't bother including more code, but if anyone had any guesses, I'd appreciate hearing your thoughts.

**EDIT:** Upon request, here's where the section that works:

```
if (self == NULL)
    {
        self = (AVL)malloc(sizeof(struct avlNode));
        self->student_id = id;
        self->left = self->right = NULL;
    }
```

And here's the code that will, when changed to this, crash the program:

```
if (!empty_tree(self))
    {
        self = (AVL)malloc(sizeof(struct avlNode));
        self->student_id = id;
        self->left = self->right = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: what error does you program give when it crashes?

Comment: Are you sure it's `if(self==NULL)` that crashed? post the code that calls this function.

Comment: Sure, I'll update the OP.

Comment: Also Joseph, it gives me the following:
`Unhandled exception at 0x00331A0C in Assignment 1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.`

Comment: The crash is probably the result of *undefined behavior* triggered elsewhere in your code that is showing up on that call.

Comment: Why you are allocating memory if `empty_tree()` returns false? Shouldn't it be allocated when function returns true (i.e `self == NULL`)?

Comment: Holy moly, I am an idiot. Thank you so much, @kuro ! The simplest answer is always the most overlooked. Which I could have marked this as the answer.